# Integrate Unity Game in iOS Application

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine

I want to integrate unity game in iOS an application on a specific screen button event. App working fine on end of the game I dismiss the view controller. on next time on click on a button, I want to open the game again it gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS I am a beginner for unity app integration in iOS.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

do you have C exceptions enabled?

Comment: have y found any solution for open unityView multiple times when required